# DyanmoDB not adding every item? Stops at 900 items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am uploading a csv that has 15,000 items to dynamodb via the 'import from s3' button on the dynamodb console. However, when it is finished and I do a 'get live item count', it says 900 when it should be 15000. Anyone know why is it not adding everything to my new table?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you had a format error. Look in CloudWatch Logs for details.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-can-now-import-amazon-s3-data-into-a-new-table/ says:

"During the import, DynamoDB might encounter errors while parsing your data. For each error, DynamoDB creates a log entry in Amazon CloudWatch Logs and keeps a count of the total number of errors encountered."